# Select distinct values one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, excel, adodb

I have the following data: column 1 with many category and column 2 with values for each category. I need to convert or pivot this information to show each value for category group across multiple columns.

```
col1      col2
----------------
1         a    
2         b 
2         c
2         d
3         e
3         f 
4         g
4         h
```

And need this result:

```
col1      col2     col3     col4   col5   col6   
-----------------------------------------------   
1         a
2         b         c       d
3         e         f 
4         g         h
```

There are no more than seven values per tb1 count(column 2)  group(column 1). All values from tb1 column 2 are different and about + 50 records.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Why is `col2` repeated?  What are the three empty columns?

Comment: Where's D for col1 (2) in your results?

Comment: How is the result different for col1 2nd row in the expected results?

Comment: I need an old priest, and a young priest.

Comment: Using ADODB in Excel, fixed value/ column in table 2. table 2 will show values from table 1 column 2 pivoted across several columns grouped by table 1 column 1 values.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: @Jerrard No, I am using ADODB.

Comment: @Jorge ADODB isn't a database, it's an interface to a database.  The question is: what kind of database is ADODB accessing?  Where does your data live?

Comment: @Jerrard The Data is in an EXCEL spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pivot your table, but your table doesn't currently contain the field that you want to pivot on ("col1", "col2", "col3", etc...).  You need a row number, partitioned by col1.  The Jet database does not provide a `ROW_NUMBER` function, so you have to fake it by joining the table to itself:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, count(*) as row_num
from [Sheet1$] t1
inner join [Sheet1$] t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 <= t1.col2
group by t1.col1, t1.col2
```

Now you can pivot on `row_num`:

```
transform Min(x.col2) select x.col1
from(
    select t1.col1, t1.col2, count(*) as row_num
    from [Sheet1$] t1
    inner join [Sheet1$] t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 <= t1.col2
    group by t1.col1, t1.col2
    )  x
group by x.col1
pivot x.row_num
```